# Issue with double pointer in LINKED LIST

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to make a data structure which contains all the monsters in the game. For some reason when I allocate new monster i get "cannot convert Monster** to p_monster {Aka monster*} in initialization. If you could help me out it would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
struct Monster {
    int x;
    int y;
    int health;
    Monster *next;
};
typedef Monster* p_monster;
class gameUtils {
protected:
  p_monster monster};
public:
gameUtils(){
monster=NULL;
...}
function(){
monster = getMonster(monster)}  // so that I can assign whatever value I want to monster->last->next through the function itself

p_monster getMonster(p_monster monster){
  p_monster newMonster = new p_monster;
        if(monster==NULL){
            monster=newMonster;

        }else{
    ....   // find last monster then create new one and pass it to caller

        return monster;   // returns new monster without any value
    }
```

Comment: Give yourself a break and use `std::list<Monster>`.  The `std::list` has already been tested and works, so that you can move on and do other coding.

Comment: Don't use manual memory management in modern C++.

Comment: `p_monster newMonster = new p_monster;` should be `p_monster newMonster = new Monster;` I think you confused yourself with the unnecessary typedef

Comment: Fyi, `p_monster {Aka monster*}` - that you are compelled to mention that is an indication of what a terrible idea hiding pointer types in typedef aliases really is. And if you don't think so, look at @drescherjm ' s comment above. I suspect he's hyper-accurate in that assessment.

Comment: I recommend modifying your coding style to always specifying the return types for function, use `void` if the function doesn't return anything.

Comment: Type-aliasing pointers is one of those things that everyone discovers to be a great idea – for two or three weeks or so. And then the pain sets in...

Comment: You should pass the `Monster` by reference.  This allows you to copy it into your list:  `Monster * p_monster = new Monster(monster_argument);`

Answer (score 3):

Type aliases are slightly more clear with `using`.

```
//typedef Monster* p_monster;
using p_monster = Monster*;
```

`p_monster` is `Monster*`. Now when you call `new T` then an object of type `T` is created and as a result you get a pointer to that object, a `T*`.

When you write:

```
p_monster newMonster = new p_monster;
```

Then `new` dynamically allocates a `p_monster`, a `Monster*`, and you get a `p_monster*`, a `Monster**`. There is no conversion from `Monster**` to `Monster*`, hence the error.

I suggest a `std::vector<Monster>` to store your monsters. Your approach for the list is intrusive, a `Monster` in your design is aware of being in a linked list, it has a `next` member. When you use a `std::vector<Monster>` you can store `Monster`s in a vector, outside of the vector, or in a different container, the `Monster` needs not care.
Also not using manual memory managment via raw pointers will make your code much simpler.

```
struct Monster {
    int x;
    int y;
    int health;
    Monster(int x,int y,int health) : x(x),y(y),health(health) {}
};

struct gameUtils {
    std::vector<Monster> monster;
    Monster& createMonster(int x,int y,int health) {
        monster.emplace_back(x,y,health);
        return monster.back();
    }
};
```

A linked list in C++ is `std::list`, though a vector profits a lot from its elements being stored in contiguous memory. It profits from that so much, that it is often superior to a `std::list` even though time complexity of some methods suggests otherwise.